# Passing Parameters from JSF to Applet not working

Tags: jsf, applet, parameter-passing

I am working on a project where I am trying to pass parameters to an applet from JSF. The values (username and roleid) which are being passed as parameters, are fetched from the managed been(loginform). I have an issue with passing these parameters since I get no values in the applet but when I output the values in my web page (for testing purposes), I can clearly see these values. When I hard code the parameter values, I can successfully get the values in the applet, but when I use the values from the manged bean, I get an empty string from the applet. How is this caused and how can I solve it?

View:

```
<p:idleMonitor onidle="#{loginform.loggout()}" timeout="60000" />

<div id="header">
    <div class="pull-left">
         Welcome: #{loginform.uname}  My Role Id:#{loginform.roleid}
        <span style="margin-left:200px;line-height: 10px;">
<h:outputLabel value= "Welcome: #{loginform.uname}" /></span>
    </div> 

<div class="pull-right">

<h:form>
<h:commandButton class="btn btn-inverse"  value="Log Out" action="# 
{loginform.loggout()}"/>
 </h:form>

</div>
</div> 

<APPLET height="900" width="100%" codebase="." 
 code="finatriall.safe.pro.FinalJApplet.class"  
archive="FinalJapplet.jar" >
<param name="username" value="#{loginform.uname}"/>
    <param name="role_id" value="loginform.roleid" />   
</APPLET> 

 <!--The section  Welcome: #{loginform.uname}  My Role Id:#
  {loginform.roleid} is used for checking whether values are 
   successfully returned from the bean-->
```

Model:

```
@ManagedBean(name="loginform", eager = true)
@SessionScoped
public class Login {
boolean isLoggedIn;
DBConnection dbcon=new DBConnection();
String username, password;
ArrayList<String> details;
String uname, pwd, message,roleid;

public String getUsername() {
return username;
}

 public void setUsername(String username) {
 this.username = username;
 }

 public String getPassword() {
  return password;
 }

 public void setPassword(String password) {
  this.password = password;
 }
 public String getUname() {
 return uname;
 }

   public void setUname(String uname) {
   this.uname = uname;
   }

 public String getRoleid() {
  return roleid;
   }

 public void setRoleid(String roleid) {
 this.roleid = roleid;
 }


 public String userLogin(){
  String path="";
  details=dbcon.loginFunction(username, password);

   if(details!=null){
      FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new
      FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Welcome", "Login 
       successful."));

        uname=details.get(0);
        roleid=details.get(2);
         System.out.println("username "+uname); 
          System.out.println("roleid "+roleid);

         path= "/main.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";//Path to launch the
         main.xhtml that 
         contains     <>Applet tag>
          isLoggedIn=true;
          System.out.println("Welcome");
           }
           else{ 
           System.out.println("Wrong details");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new   
        FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Wrong Credentials", 
         "User not   found."));

        path="";
         }
        return path;
         }
       public String loggout()
       {
       FacesContext  ctx=FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        HttpSession sess=
        (HttpSession)ctx.getExternalContext().getSession(false);

        sess.invalidate();
        isLoggedIn=false;
         return "/index.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
           }
```

Applet:

```
 public void init() {
 // changeTheme();


jDesktopPane1 = new JDesktopPane();
jDesktopPane1.setBackground(Color.white);
String username=getParameter("separate_jvm");
String roleid = getParameter("role_id");
System.out.println("Role Id: "+roleid);
System.out.println("Username: "+username);
}
```

Comment: `String username=getParameter("separate_jvm");` Huh? Are you really posting and running the code you think you do?

Comment: I realized that I was using the wrong string name when calling the getParameter method. I changed it to "username" just as I had called the parameter in the webpage. Despite my mistake in passing the wrong string name in the getParameter method, String roleid in the applet contains a correct call to the getParameter method. Why doesn't it return any value?